# Rotating left int list with deque returns None

Tags: python, list, deque

I am just wondering if there's a syntax error on my end. I have an int list and I want to rotate them left. I used deque and rotate(-1) but it's returning None.

An example of outcome I am looking for:

```
list1 = [1, 2 , 3]
rotateLeft = [2, 3, 1]
```

This is the code snippet.

```
from collections import deque

def rotate_left(nums):        
    return deque(nums).rotate(-1)

print rotate_left([1, 2, 3])
>>> None
```

Can anyone tell me if I did something wrong?

Comment: Methods that mutate mutable objects in Python almost always return `None`.  `list.sort()`, `dict.update()`, `list.append()`, on & on.

Comment: Why not lst[-1:] + lst[:-1]?

Comment: @Harold - Actually it wasn't so much about the method. I was wondering why I was getting a None value. But thank you for your alternate method. This one rotate to the right I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`deque.rotate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) returns nothing.

So `rotate_left` should be:

```
def rotate_left(nums):
    q = deque(nums)
    q.rotate(-1)
    return list(q)
```

Almost functions/methods in standard library that modify data return nothing.
(Exception: [dict.setdefault](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), ..)

Comment: Thank you. Can you briefly explain why I need to list it again?

Comment: @Cryssie, `return q` is okay if you don't need list but just any sequence is acceptable. I used `list(..)` because you specified `rotateLeft = [2, 3, 1]` as a list.